# Unable to Create Application, is this planned 'no new users' time or something else?

Tags: google-app-engine

Very simple problem - stuck at step 0.

I've downloaded the SDK, got my application working locally etc.

However when I visit https://appengine.google.com/start and click 'Create Application' I get a page that says

**Server Error**
A server error has occurred.

This is my first time using App Engine so I can't access dashboards/control panels/account areas or whatever is deeper than the non-functional 'Create Application' button.

I realise that this isn't a programming problem (well, in a sense it is but it's not *my* programming problem) but I'd really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login at [appengine](http://appengine.google.com) with your gmail account.

Comment: I am logged in, I've tried logging in with another google account I have and that doesn't work either.

Comment: im not sure but i tried new gmail account and didn't encounter the problem.

Comment: Brilliant, that's the problem! thank you! They really should have the page say that though.